# list index out of range error from previous view when rendering a different view

Tags: django, django-views

Apologies if I'm missing something daft here but I'm new to Django and I can't work this out.

I'm creating a basic reddit style app focusing on cryptocurrency. I have a view which gets price data from an API and displays it as well as any posts specific to that coin:

views.py:

```
def coin_posts(request, id):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        coin_display = {}
        post = Post.objects.filter(coin_name=id)
        api = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&ids=%s&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false' % id
        response = requests.get(api)

        data = response.json()
        coin = data[0]        

        coin_data = Coins(
            coin_id = coin['id'],
            coin_name = coin['name'],
            coin_price = coin['current_price'],
            market_cap = coin['market_cap'],
            rank = coin['market_cap_rank'],
            price_change = coin['price_change_24h'],
            slug = coin['symbol'],
            image_url = coin['image']
        )
        coin_data.save()
        coin_display = Coins.objects.filter(coin_id=id)

        return render(request, 'coins.html', { 
            'post': post,
            'coin_display': coin_display,
            'post_form': PostForm()
            },
        )
```

I want to be able to click on each post to view any comments related to said post, as I haven't got that far yet I just wish to be able to view that single post on another page. So each post has the following link on the template:

```
<a href="{% url 'coin_detail' slug=i.slug  %}">Comments</a>
```

and here are the corresponding URLs and view:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"), 
    path('<str:id>/', views.coin_posts, name='coin_posts'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.post_detail, name='coin_detail'),
]

def post_detail(request, slug):
    post = Post.objects.filter(slug=slug)

    return render(request, 'coin_detail.html', { 
        'post': post,
        },
    )
```

The problem is when I click on the link, I get the error: list index out of range
Which is referencing the coin = data[0] in the first view.

I can see that it's trying to populate the database, but because there's no GET data there's no list to index. My question is why is that happening? If I've clicked a link which calls the post_detail function, why is it executing the code in the coin_posts function?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the url paths. The path of coin_posts "str:id/" is equal to the path of post_detail 'slug:slug/'. The only difference between these two urls is that str will accept only string while slug will match any slug string consisting of ASCII letters or numbers, plus the hyphen and underscore characters ([reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/#path-converters)).
Try defferenciating the path adding a different path for example:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"), 
    path('coin_posts/<str:id>/', views.coin_posts, name='coin_posts'),
    path('post_detail/<slug:slug>/', views.post_detail, name='coin_detail'),
]
```

Comment: I never would have thought the issue would have been with the urls, that worked a treat. Thank you so much!